# Split output of loop by columns used as input

Tags: python, loops, numpy, feature-detection

Hi I'm relatively new to Python and am currently working on trying to measure the width of features in an image. The resolution of my image is 1m so measuring the width should be easier. I've managed to select certain columns or rows of the image and extract the necessary data using loops and such. My code is below:

```
subset = imarray[:,::500]#(imarray.shape[1]/2):(imarray.shape[1]/2)+1]
subset[(subset > 0) & (subset <= 17)] = 1
subset[(subset > 17)] = 0


width = []
count = 0

for i in np.arange(subset.shape[1]):
    column = subset[:,i]
    for value in column:
        if (value == 1):
            count += 1
            width.append(count)
            width_arr = np.array(width).astype('uint8')
        else:
            count = 0


final = np.split(width_arr, np.argwhere(width_arr == 1).flatten())
final2 = [x for x in final if x != []]


width2 = []


for array in final2:
    width2.append(max(array))
width2 = np.array(width2).astype('uint8')
print width2
```

I can't figure out how to split the output up so it shows the results for each column or row individually. Instead all I've been able to do is to append the data to an empty list and here's the output for that:

```
[ 70  35   4   2   5  36   4   5   2  51  97   4 228   3  21  47   7  21
  23  58 126   4 111   2   2   5   3   2  18  15   6  19   3   3  12  15
   6   8   2   4   6  88 122  24  14  49  73  57  74   6 179   8   3   2
   6   3 184   9   3  19  24   3   2   2   3 255  30   8 191  33 127   5
   3  27 112   2  24   2   5   2  10  30  10   6  37   2  38   6  12  17
  44  67  23   5 101  10   9   4   6   4 255 136   5 255 255 255 255  26
 255 235 148   4 255 199   3   2 114  87 255 109  69  12  41  20  30  57
  72  89  32]
```

So these are the widths of the features in all the columns appended together. How do I use my loop or another method to split these up into individual numpy arrays representing each column I've sliced out of the original?

It seems like I am almost there but I can't seem to figure that last step out and it's driving me nuts.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: after staring at this for awhile longer I found that by adding an empty list inside the for loop and appending that to the original empty list solved my problem.                                                                                                         So I ended up with a list of lists